# Trying to filter an array of objects that has a property value that is also an array

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have this object inside a json:

```
{
"group": "A",
"id": "50"
"person": [
    {
      "name": 'Joe',
      "age": '29'
      "hobbies": ["Watching movies", "Gaming"]
    },
    {
        "name": 'Jessie',
      "age": '27'
      "hobbies": ["Gaming", "Reading"]
   }
    ]
}
```

I want to filter the people by their hobbies. For example, if I filter by Gaming I need to create an array of objects with Joe and Jessie. If I filter by Reading, then the array would only have Jessie.

Here is my code:

```
    import { people } from '../../../data/index' // this is the json I shower above

    let filteredArray;
  filteredArray = people.filter(person => {
    return person.hobbies == "Gaming";
  })
```

this doesn't work, but if change the hobbies to a single word on the json, like this:

```
    {
        "name": 'Jessie',
      "age": '27'
      "hobbies": "Gaming"
   }
```

then it work just fine.

So is there a way to use filter with a array of hobbies to check if one of the values match my condition?

I'm using only vanilla Js and I only want to support chrome.

Sorry for any english mistake or if the question is not clear enought, I'm still in the beggining of my studies

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `includes` method. Because you are trying to search in array:

```
const filteredArray = people.filter(person => {
    return person.hobbies.includes("Gaming");
})
```

```js
const data = {
  group: 'A',
  id: '50',
  person: [
    {
      name: 'Joe',
      age: '29',
      hobbies: ['Watching movies', 'Gaming']
    },
    {
      name: 'Jessie',
      age: '27',
      hobbies: ['Gaming', 'Reading']
    }
  ]
};

const result = data.person.filter(el => el.hobbies.includes('Gaming'));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: I didn't know about this method, Thanks!